# Parking randomly in Anylogic

Tags: random, simulation, anylogic, parking

I am using AnyLogic's Traffic Road Library and I know it's possible in the car Source module to define the initial position of the car in a parking lot.

I want the parking lot space to be randomly chosen. I know there is this function `randomFreeSpaceIndex()` that returns the index of randomly chosen free parking space.

But I do not know how to call it on my car source or use it with the CarMoveTo tool. Here is my [model](https://cloud.anylogic.com/#/model/eb9dc1a2-e7df-4c01-a1a2-6e32581794e6;mode=SETTINGS) so far.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that you can't with the standard parking lot, so you have to unfortunately create many parkinglots with 1 parking space as you can see in the following image:
[image: parking spot]

With that being done, now you can select a random parking space with a model that could look for example like this:
[image: model]

In this model I created a collection of parkingLots... all with 1 parking space:
[image: collection]

In the select output block you ask if there is space available:

```
for(ParkingLot p : parkingSpaces){
    if(p.nFree()>0)
        return true;
} 
return false;
```

And in the carMoveTo you call the function selectRandomParkingSpace():
[image: randomParkingSpace]

selectRandomParkingSpace uses the following code:

```
ArrayList <ParkingLot> freeSpaces=new ArrayList();
for(ParkingLot p : parkingSpaces){
    if(p.nFree()>0){
        freeSpaces.add(p);
    }
}
int randomSpace=uniform_discr(0,freeSpaces.size()-1);
return freeSpaces.get(randomSpace);
```

That is my solution.